# uiComponent Form. How to show data from DB table

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, data-provider

I'm trying to understand uiForm Component. I'm stucked in My module settings page. I created database table with settings in one row. And now I must to get default data and show them in Form. 
My main questions:

- How get data from table and show it in e.g. input field?
- What structure should have DataProvider::getData() return array?
- When I even use die() in  getData() function nothings happened. It isn't executed? why?
- In documentation is

  > js_config -> config -> provider - specifies the name of the component data.

but it isn't working . I gets error in console.log. It's (working?) for js_config -> provider like is now in my file.

Table name is: **correctemail_settings**

Below are my example files: 
**settings_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">settings_form.settings_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">settings_form.settings_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
    <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="settings_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">iDesign\Correctemail\Model\Settings\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">settings_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">settings_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">settings_id</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<fieldset name="settings">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Settings</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
    <field name="settings_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">settings_id</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">correctemail_settings</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
    <field name="formId">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">correctemail_settings</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">formId</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
 </fieldset>
```

**DataProvider.php**

```
namespace iDesign\Correctemail\Model\Settings;

use \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use \iDesign\Correctemail\Model\ResourceModel\Settings\Collection;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
  public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    Collection $settingsCollection,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
  ) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collection = $settingsCollection;
  }
  public function getData()
  {
    /*if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
        $this->getCollection()->load(1);
    }
    $items = $this->getCollection()->getData();*/

    return ['settings' =>[
            'settings_id' => 1,
            'formId' => 'exampleValue']];
  }
}
```

As you see I even tried to return static data to understand how it should be defined.

Comment: Try looking at a core example such as CMS blocks and copy from that.

Comment: In magento2/sample_form there aren't any data  provided into form. Others like product form in magento uses also grid/list (don't remember exactly) it is a bit to complex for  my needs.  I'm looking here for help because I doesn't find any solution. in core/github/stack/documentation. My main problem is to understand dependencies between uiForm / xml / DataProvider / and js template creating.  If you have any specific materials it will be helpfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My main problem that DataProvider::getData() function weren't executed was because it didn't know which row to populate. When I added /settings_id/1/ into an url then this function was called.

And return value should be set like this:

> return [1 => ['settings' => $item]]

where

> [$selectedId => [$fieldsetName => $ArrayOfitemValues]]

I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: but how do you know the id of the settings to return in the getData() function. I saw examples iterating over all entries which doesnt make sense like here https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-2/

Comment: The collection of the `DataProvider` gets filtered by id from url on
 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ab300352979fc42e93c433daa711ba99ce685b86/app/code/Magento/Ui/Component/Form.php#L66 .